# What route would I use to check a Rails JSON API to see if a user is logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I've created a backend Rails JSON API.

I have a sessions controller, and on #create, if the user authenticates their username and password correctly, the JSON api returns a token to the user. The user uses this token to perform actions which require authentication.

However, I have a need for my client side to KNOW whether the user is currently logged in. The client cannot re-login otherwise it will change the token. I just want the client to pass the user and token information to the API, and for the API to respond that the user is either still logged in or not.

1) What route should I use for this? #show? #index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client side has a token, then isn't the user logged in? When someone logs out, doesn't the client discard the token, and the server invalidate/destroy the session?

If the token/session can expire server-side, then you just need an authenticated endpoint that the client can hit that does nothing more than see if the authentication token is still valid according to the server.

You can define this route in any manner you see fit.

'index' typically requests a list of resources (a bunch of sessions?) which isn't what you want, 'show' typically says return a representation of a resource, also not a good fit in my opinion.

'valid' might work, 'alive', whatever makes sense to you.

Perhaps:

```
resources :sessions do
  member do
    get 'alive'
  end
end
```

Comment: How do I create a custom route like that? I added :alive to my routes.rb file but it doesn't appear when I run 'rake routes'.

Comment: Not sure how you spec'ed :alive, but updated the answer with an idea.